# Wired network connection drops frequently

Tags: 13.04, networking, realtek, wired

Network connection being dropped even after updating the driver to the latest realtek one r8168-8.037.00. I am running Ubuntu 13.04.

I need to usually reboot my router to fix and or the cable modem also. Other systems connected don't have this problem.

[LINUX driver for kernel 3.x and 2.6.x and 2.4.x](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2)

Also I added the following as well.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

`echo on | sudo tee /sys/class/net/eth0/device/power/control`

Below shows my `lspci -v` output I put in bold the Ethernet item in question

```
 03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1449
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
        I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
        Memory at d1004000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
        Memory at d1000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Expansion ROM at d1010000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: r8169**
```

Comment: Does disabling IPv6 help?

Answer (score 0):

This may be an unexpected solution, but are there any other 2.4GHz devices, such as cordless landline phones, baby monitors or wireless headsets in the vicinity? Your particular computer could have a weak signal, and when combined with the interference, that could cause the problem.

Oftentimes those are using the same ISM band http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band frequencies, but since they are not WiFi devices they can jam the WiFi band and break your connection. Folks who do wireless consumer support often call those frequencies the 'junk' band because some consumer devices do pretty horrible things to WiFi signals.